# Перенос таблицы HTML в Excel

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста. Имеется программа, которую я не доделал. Цель задачи - составить программу в java так, чтобы она таблицу html переносила в excel. Буду признателен.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.AutoShape;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Line;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.ShapeTypes;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Table;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.TableCell;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.TextBox;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.RichTextRun;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.util.StringUtil;

public class Samplefile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("test");
        File fl=new File("test.html");
        FileInputStream finp=new FileInputStream(fl);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(finp);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader( isr );
        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        ArrayList<String> arrstr = new ArrayList<String>();

        //читаем строку, а не чар
        String s;
        while ( ( s = buff.readLine() ) != null ) {
            strBuff.append(s);
            arrstr.add(s);
        }

        String str= strBuff.toString();

          Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
          CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
          Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("test");
          Row row = sheet1.createRow((short)0);
            // Create a cell and put a value in it.
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(1);
            CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(
                createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"));
            // Or do it on one line.
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(
            createHelper.createRichTextString("This is a string"));
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(true);
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue("ddd");
            cell=row.createCell(5);

            cell.setCellValue(Calendar.getInstance());
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            cell=row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue(new Date());
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            cell = row.createCell(7,HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR);

          String file="test.xls";
          FileOutputStream outfl = new FileOutputStream(file);
          wb.write(outfl);
          outfl.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Не получается написать цикл для того, что бы считывало именно то, что находится между тегами `<td></td>`, к примеру.

Comment: Парсер нужен.

Comment: Я новичек еще в этом. не могу точно сказать, знаю ли я это. Мне поставили эту задачу и ее нужно сделать, как можно быстрее. Если можете чем-либо помочь, помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: есть парсеры типа DOM, SAX и тд, если нету время разбираться в них, напиши примитивный парсер сам, типа "если чар = <td>, тогда в буфер пишем слова, пока не будет чар = </td>, в конце буфер выводи в файл"

Comment: Вот в том то и дело, что на теории все понятно, а на практике не могу нифига сделать. Столько материала перечитал уже. Если не трудно, можете мне помочь по моей программе написать?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Читаем строку, а не чар

String s;
while ( s = buff.readLine() != null ) {
    if(s.trim() = "<td>") {
        while ( s = buff.readLine() != "</td>") {
            strBuff.append(s);
            arrstr.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно как-то так =)

Comment: Какие ошибки?

Comment: @Gorets, 

    if(s.trim() = "<td>") 

Это из какого языка ? Считаете, что это сравнение в Java ?

@арт, сравнить прочитанную строку (убрав пробелы в начале и конце) с другой строкой:

    if ( s.trim().equals("<td>")) {
        ...     
    }

Но ! Почему Вы решили, что кроме тега в строке ничего нет ?

Смелое предположение.

Comment: а я все смотрю и думаю что глаза режит

Comment: Вы (@арт), вместо своей программы лучше образец данных, которые хотите конвертировать приведите. 

Всем ведь лень общий случай html разбирать. Советов в этом плане Вам уже написали. 

И еще, какая ОС и почему обязательно Java ?

Comment: windows. а java потому что задание на этом языке нужно сделать. за образец данных,которые нужно конвертировать можно взять любую таблицу html. но могу сам код таблицы скинуть если вам нужно...

Comment: Вот тут-то (*взять любую таблицу html*), как говорится, и собака порылась... 

Т.е. у Вас не однократный перенос данных, а **учебное задание** ?

Comment: это не учебное задание. мне это задание дали на работе. дело в том что нужно что бы в любом html документе где есть таблица,данная программа должна переносить ее в excel файл. а я с java столкнулся впервые и понять не могу как оно делается. немного написал программы и все.